# Determining the primitive root $g$ of $p$, given $B=g^b \pmod p$

Tags: diffie-hellman, modular-arithmetic

This is related to Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Suppose you're given a prime $p, b \in \{0,1,...,p-2\}$, and $B$, such that
$$ 
B= g^b \pmod p. 
$$

Assuming that $$\gcd(b, p-1)=1$$ How could you determine the primitive root $g$?

Comment: Aw, come on, $g = B^{1/b}$...

Comment: Maybe you could explain the reasoning, instead of a snarky one-liner. Just because its obvious to you doesn't mean its obvious to everyone

Comment: Well, "just" compute the b-th root of B, which is possible as you are in a prime field. [Related PDF Slides](https://spark-university.s3.amazonaws.com/stanford-crypto/slides/10.3-numth-annotated.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the resource. The solution is obvious,  provided there is a b-th root of B. The proof of that fact is what I'm interested in.

Comment: @fkraiem We get it, you know the answer. This is not helpful though, and a sure way to prevent new users from staying around on this site. On that note, welcome JackB.

Comment: @curveenthusiast Are you serious? This was a very low quality question, not deserving of more than that; for one thing it was probably a homework dump, which is discouraged in the faq sections that everyone is supposed to read before posting.

Comment: @fkraiem Not homework. Just learning some basics. On the other hand, if you can't even be bothered to help beyond snarky one-liners, then why even bother posting? It's a fair question for those of us who are new to the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\gcd(b,p-1)=1$ you have  $u\cdot b + y\cdot (p-1) = 1$ where $u=b^{-1} \bmod {(p-1)}$. With Euler's theorem $B^{p-1} \equiv 1\bmod p$ you get
$$g \equiv B^u \bmod p.$$

Right you are with your comment, I have included the changes. Euler's theorem is used at the penultimate step: 
This is the 'easy case' on page 4 of the reference given by SEJPM
$$g^u \equiv (B^u)^b \equiv B^{ub} \equiv B^{1-y(p-1)} 
\equiv B \cdot (B^{p-1})^{-y}\equiv B \cdot 1^{-y}\equiv B \bmod p$$
Example: $p=11, b=7, B=4$.  Compute:
$$u \equiv 7^{-1} \equiv  3 \bmod {10}$$
$$g \equiv 4^3  \equiv 9 \bmod {11}$$
and check:
$$9^7 \equiv 4 \bmod 11$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$ u = b^{-1} mod (p-1) $$ ? Also, I'm not clear how you arrive at the result from Euler's theorem.

Comment: @JackB Yes, $\bmod(p-1)$ is meant (the parenthesization is a bit ambiguous). By definition, we have $ub=1+k(p-1)$ for some $k$, hence $$B^u\equiv g^{bu}\equiv g^{1+k(p-1)}\equiv g\cdot(g^{p-1})^k\pmod{p}\text.$$ By the theorem, $g^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$, hence any power of this is also congruent to $1$ modulo $p$, thus $B^u\equiv g\pmod p$.